# Angular - Dependency Injection in e2e Test

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, e2e-testing

I am struggling with DI in my test.

The case is simple. I have a service and when testing I just want to inject a different service.

I did:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.overrideProvider( AuthService, {useValue: MockAuthService(??)});
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
    providers: [ AuthService ]
  }).compileComponents();
  page = new AppPage();
}
```

MockAuthService inherits from real AuthService. There I inject another service in the constructor. I dont know how to do that here.

Is there another way? What is wrong?

Thx a lot and best regards,
Nikolaus

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
        providers: [ 
            {provide: AuthService, useClass: MockAuthService}
        ]
    }).compileComponents();
    page = new AppPage();
}
```

Comment: Thx, but I get that: - Failed: Cannot read property 'injector' of null
          at TestBed._createCompilerAndModule (/execroot/packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:407:23)
          at TestBed.compileComponents (/execroot/packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:334:29)
          at Function.TestBed.compileComponents (/execroot/packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:116:66)

Comment: ok, added this: TestBed.initTestEnvironment( BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting()); before ..

Comment: but get: - Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for MockAuthService: (?).

Comment: I added: @Injectable() but does not help

Comment: @Nikolaus which angular version you have? I would suggest to not extend ``AuthService`` because if you have there any other dependencies like ``HttpClient`` test module would need them aswell.

Comment: I use version 6. On the Angular website they do it with beforeEach(async(() => { .. but when I add async I get: 
      - Failed: Zone is needed for the async() test helper but could not be found. Please make sure that your environment includes zone.js/dist/zone.js